# setting a property from data in json-ld

Tags: json-ld

I have a pair of values, the first gives the property (e.g. "prop")  the second the value for the property (e.g. "val"). I want to convert them to an RDF triple, e.g.

```
<http://example.com/x1> <http://example.com/prop> "val" .
```

but I cannot see how to achieve this with a json-ld context.

The solution I have are two lines in the context, which produce two triples, one for the "prop" as a value and the next with the "val" as a value.

In the context I have

```
"propSource" "property" ,
"valSource" "value" ,
```

and the JSON values are, for example,

```
"property" : "propertyKindA" , 
"value" : "Joe Doe" ,
```

which then produces

```
<http://example.com/x1> <http://example.com/property> "propertyKindA";
                         <http://example.com/value "Joe Doe".
```

but I would like:

```
 <http://example.com/x1> <http://example.com/propertyKindA> "Joe Doe" .
```

Is it possible, to achieve a better solution with jsonld?

(The example is a much simplified version of my code).